# Failure to display images on the http page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http, https

I am uploading png pictures in asp.net mvc. And I save their address in the database. I get a 404 error while displaying some images on the http page. Whereas on https, the images are loaded and the images are exist.
This problem exists only for png images or a specific folder. This is not a problem with jpeg images.

please help me

`<img class="default-img" src="@item.Image" alt="">`

`item.Image="/images/Post/166362.png"`

Comment: Did you try to remove first forward slash in the image src? I mean you tried like this       `item.Image="images/Post/166362.png"` if you could post more code we will help

Comment: item is a record of table.
item={ int ID;
string Image;
.....
}

Comment: convert the image src to http ://example.com/images/Post/166362.png in the browser. And I get the 404 error, but if the url convert to https ://example.com/images/Post/166362.png, the image loads and I don't get the error.
This error happens sometimes.
And sometimes it is the other way around.
https ://example.com/images/Post/166362.png ==>404 error and
http: //example.com/images/Post/166362.png==>No error